# Export jsonfile from symfony

Tags: jquery, ajax

I try to export a json file from my controller by ajax, but nothing happens.
Anyone can say me where i failed ?

Here my ajax :

```
$.ajax({
        url: '{{ path('export_index', {'type': 'json'}) }}',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {data: data}
    }).done(function() {

    });
```

And here my route controller :

```
public function export(Request $request):Response {
            header('Content-Type: application/json');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=data.json');
            header('Expires: 0'); //No caching allowed
            header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
            header('Content-Length: ' . strlen($mydata));
            file_put_contents('php://output', $mydata);
            return new Response();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use proper syntax [$.ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

```
const base_url = 'myurl/';

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    // url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts",
    url: base_url+"export_index?type=excel",
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: "json",
    //data: JSON.stringify({data: data}),
    success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    },
    error: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    },
    done: function() {
        console.log("done");
    }
});
```

```js
const base_url = 'myurl/';

$.ajax({
    type: "get",
    url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts",
    //url: base_url+"export_index?type=excel",
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: "json",
    //data: JSON.stringify({data: data}),
    success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    },
    error: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    },
    done: function() {
        console.log("done");
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: That don't export my json too. For now that work only if i don't ajax and go directly in my url : myurl/export_index?type=excel

Comment: What inside `{data: data}`

Comment: {foo: 'bar', baz: 1}

Comment: @Ygg69 Just add proper url, and data, also i have added a working example

Comment: I have test with your code, but my file dosnt download. I need again to access to my directurl without ajax if i want get it

Comment: What is the error in console? What you see in browser when you direct access?

Comment: Finally its ok, juste bad understanding of my part ! All works, thank you for your help :)